# Rails number_field_tag input not valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this nested form:

```
  <div class="nested-fields">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <%= select_tag "ingredients", "", class: 'ingredients'%>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
          <%= number_field_tag "quantity", id: "quantity"%>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <%= f.label :price, id: 'price' %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <%= f.label :total_amount, id: "total_amount", readonly: true %>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2">
          <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove", f,  class: "btn btn-sm btn-danger" %>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When I enter a value on quantity, it calculates the line total.

```
document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", function() {
  $('#quantity').on('keyup',function(){
   var quantity = $(this).val();
   var price = $('#price').val();
   var total = (quantity*price)
   $('#total_amount').html(total);
});
});
```

Quantity field is a decimal:

```
t.decimal :quantity, :decimal, :precision => 8, :scale => 2
```

But when I enter a value on quantity field i receive on console:

> The specified value "{:id=\u003E\"quantity\",
>   :input_html=\u003E{:value=\u003E\"1.00000000\"}}" is not a valid
>   number. The value must match to the following regular expression:
>   -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

Why is this happening? How can I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> number_field_tag(name, value = nil, options = {})

You need to correct your `number_field_tag` like below

```
<%= number_field_tag "quantity", nil, id: "quantity" %>
```

Moreover you **can't** extract the values of `price` and `total` by defining as **labels**. You need to define them as **input fields**

```
<%= f.text_field :price, id: 'price' %>
<%= f.text_field :total_amount, id: "total_amount", readonly: true %>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The error disappeared from console, but total_amount is always updated to 0. If I change to <%= f.text_field :price, id: 'price' %>
<%= f.text_field :total_amount, id: "total_amount", readonly: true %> price and total_amount are not updated anymore, I can only enter values manually

Comment: @Catmal Try debugging the function. Check whether the function is being called.

Comment: The problem is related to something else. <%= number_field_tag "quantity", nil, id: "quantity" %> fixes the error for which I asked a solution. I'm going to accept the answer